# Swapping column locations in a row R

Tags: r

I have a data frame consisting of dozens of rows. I would like to change in only one row the order of the columns and set the first column to be empty. This is a bad row:
[image]

And I have to do it:
[image]

Comment: May we ask how you ended up here?  If you have the possibility to perhaps scrub the data before bringing it into R, that might be preferable to fixing it in your current situation.  Also, there are possible type issues, if e.g. the phone column is numeric and the name column is not.

Comment: I was looking for a solution to my problem on your site. I have a data scraping program and unfortunately after receiving a data frame on one line the data is not completed. So I need to rearrange the columns for this row.

Comment: I wrote this code: data <- subset(ans[10,], select=c(4,1,2,3))
data[,1] <- NA
ans[10,] = data

Comment: I don't see nothing wrong with that code. Note that you can use any column number where `4` is (in the `select` argument).

Comment: The problem is only when I let go a few times the program will constantly change the values in the row.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by finding the index of that column and then reassigning it.

```
index <- which(dataframe$Name == "607658123" & 
               dataframe$Phone == "London" & 
               dataframe$City == "john@gmail.com")
```

This will set the row position to index. Also note I put the Name column which is a number in quotes because I'm assuming it was coerced to character.

Then you can reset that whole row:

```
dataframe[index,] <- c("", 607658123, "London", "john@gmail.com")
```

Hope this helps!